Android websettings.setcachemode is globally?
I called clearCache in an Android WebView to delete the cache. However, I found out that this method works globally for the application’s WebView.
clearCache
Added in API level 1

public void clearCache (boolean includeDiskFiles)
Clears the resource cache. Note that the cache is per-application, so this will clear the cache for all WebViews used.

Parameters
includeDiskFiles boolean: if false, only the RAM cache is cleared


So, I found an alternative: WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE. Is this setting global or does it apply only to the specific WebView object?
Feel free to ask if you need any more help!
//is called
webView?.clearCache(true)

//i want this
webview.WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE


what exactly do you want to achieve after disabling cache?

I am creating an Android WebView SDK. I only want to clear the cache of the WebView within the SDK without affecting other WebViews.

Disabling cache could be a choice due to multiple reasons.

Try using setAppCacheEnabled and setAppCacheMaxSize to limit the cache size to very little , lower cache size will result in faster cleanup.

Ex: wv.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1);
OR

If you don't need the cached data then simply set setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE); , which means
"Don't use the cache, load from the network", even though data is cached.

In-short, simply ignore the cached data, android will take care of it.
OR

you can also try the below code for no-caching,

Note: this is only available for Android API 8+
    Map<String, String> noCacheHeaders = new HashMap<String, String>(2);
    noCacheHeaders.put("Pragma", "no-cache");
    noCacheHeaders.put("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    view.loadUrl(url, noCacheHeaders);

OR

Clear the cache every-time whenever page load finishes.
Something like this in the WebViewClient.
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
super.onPageFinished(view, url);
view.clearCache(true);
}


OR

You can try deleting whole cached database at once.
 context.deleteDatabase("webview.db");
 context.deleteDatabase("webviewCache.db");



This might give a bit faster result, hope so.

Thank you for explaining the various methods to clear the cache in an Android WebView.
My question is whether these methods work globally within the app for all WebViews (like pauseTimers()) or if they only affect the specific WebView instance.
This is because I am developing a WebView SDK and need the methods to affect only the particular WebView object.
